# Animate Divs Individually in Loop with Pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to get a looping animation with each box showing individually.  To give you a better idea of exactly how the animation should work:

Nothing showing > Red box animates in, shown for 5 seconds > Red Box animates out > Pause for 10 seconds > Green Box animations in, shown for 5 seconds > etc.

I managed to accomplish this with a sort of complicated JQuery function, so I was hoping to post here and see if there was a more simple way to do this.

[Link to JS Fiddle (The JS in this link is not working, but you can see what I started with)](http://jsfiddle.net/zw0fdbyn/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="red" class="box"></div>
    <div id="green" class="box"></div>
    <div id="blue" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    animation: box .6s ease-in;
}

#red {
    background: red;
}

#green {
    background: green;
}

#blue {
    background: blue;
}

@keyframes box {                                                            
  0% {opacity: 0;transform: translateY(-40px);}
  100%{opacity: 1;transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

Comment: Does this have to loop forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very easily with jQuery promises:

```
var p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
$('div.box').each(function(i, div) {
  p = p.then(function() {
    $(div).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut().delay(1000);
    return $(div).promise();
  });
});
```

```js
var p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();

$('div.box').each(function(i, div) {
  p = p.then(function() {
    $(div).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut().delay(1000);
    return $(div).promise();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: box .6s ease-in;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes box {                                                            
  0% {opacity: 0;transform: translateY(-40px);}
  100%{opacity: 1;transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="red" class="box"></div>
  <div id="green" class="box"></div>
  <div id="blue" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Looping it:

```
(function loop() {
  var p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
  $('div.box').each(function(i, div) {
    p = p.then(function() {
      $(div).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut().delay(1000);
      return $(div).promise();
    });
  });
  p.then(loop);
}());
```

```js
(function loop() {
  var p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
  $('div.box').each(function(i, div) {
    p = p.then(function() {
      $(div).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut().delay(1000);
      return $(div).promise();
    });
  });
  p.then(loop);
}());
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: box .6s ease-in;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes box {                                                            
  0% {opacity: 0;transform: translateY(-40px);}
  100%{opacity: 1;transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="red" class="box"></div>
  <div id="green" class="box"></div>
  <div id="blue" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for.  Is there a way to repeat this function easily?  Also, is there a way to add a pause between each animation and/or the all three animations?

Comment: Repeat it? As in a forever loop? You can add more animations to the `$(div)` and the next animations on the other elements will be chained once the `queue` for `$(div)` is done. For example, you could just add another delay after `fadeOut()` if you want to delay the next animation.

Comment: Yes, after the animations are complete for each one, it repeats the full cycle again, forever.  I was able to add another pause by simply adding a .delay after the fade out.  I'm not too familiar with newer JQuery, so I'm hoping that's correct.

Comment: Yes that's correct. You can loop it if you work with a recursive promise pattern, although I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Maybe make the  .each function it's own function, and call it via set interval?

Comment: @DRBC, I've added an example of how to loop it with a recursive promise pattern. I generally don't use them for this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can hanlde it with a recursive method, using following logic:

```js
var $boxes = $('.box');

(function animateBox(i) {
    $boxes.eq(i).addClass('animate').one('animationend', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).hide().show(0).addClass('reverse').one('animationend', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('animate');
                if(++i < $boxes.length) setTimeout(animateBox, 10000, i);
            });
        }.bind(this), 5000);
    });
})(0);
```

```css
.box.animate {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    animation: box .6s ease-in;
}
.box.animate.reverse {
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
#red {
    background: red;
}
#green {
    background: green;
}
#blue {
    background: blue;
}
@keyframes box {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="red" class="box"></div>
    <div id="green" class="box"></div>
    <div id="blue" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Here for infinite loop:

```
(function animateBox(i) {
    $boxes.eq(i).addClass('animate').one('animationend', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).hide().show(0).addClass('reverse').one('animationend', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('animate reverse');
                setTimeout(animateBox, 10000, ++i < $boxes.length ? i : 0);
            });
        }.bind(this), 5000);
    });
})(0);
```

### -jsFiddle sample-

 (with shorter delays)